# How to add resources to Jar

Tags: java, android, jar, apk, disassembly

I'm actually trying to repack a JAR file (after noping out some lines that cause conflicts) and here's my approach:

1. Convert Jar into Dex (with dex2jar). It's worth noting that resources like jpgs are not packed along into Dex.
2. Disassemble Dex into Smali and make modifications.
3. Assemble Smali into Dex.
4. Convert Dex into Jar (with jar2dex).
5. jar uf my.jar resource1.jpg resource2.jpg

At last, the Jar doesn't seem to work. I checked the Jar with JD-GUI but found nothing wrong with the modified block of code. Anything wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you are trying to do, android-apktool should be what you need to repack a modified apk:
http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Comment: It's a Jar, not exactly an APK. Do you think it's viable?